# Reported speech more than 2 verbs in the past

Tags: reported-speech

How can I report this sentence:
"I thought u wanted to  dance"

He told me :he had thought I had wanted to dance

Or

He told me :he had thought I wanted to dance
Which one?

Comment: Please spell _you_ correctly and leave out the colons, which are unnecessary. There is no need to use the perfect tense for both verbs.

Comment: @KateBunting Ok, but why?